# Two-parter: Why doesn't this code call the function I want, and can I do this without making a separate function for it?

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7

This is a part of a larger program, what's supposed to happen is the Score.print_points() line calls the print_points() function in class Score, then print the self.points variable.

```
class Score(object):

    def __init__(self, points):
        self.points = points

    def set_score(self):
        self.points = 100

    # This is going to be used for something else   
    def change_score(self, amount):
        self.points += amount

    def print_points(self):
        print self.points

Score.print_points()
```

When I run it, though, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sandbox.py", line 15, in <module>
    Score.print_points()
TypeError: unbound method print_points() must be called with Score instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

I'm really unfamiliar with lingo, but I thought that I was calling with the Score instance as my first argument?

As for the second part: Is there a way of making printing self.points without making a separate function within the Score class to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're calling print_points on the class itself, not an instance of that class.

Try

```
>>> score = Score(0)
>>> score.print_points()
0
```

For your second question:

> As for the second part: Is there a way of making printing self.points without making a separate function within the Score class to do so?

You could just do

```
>>> print score.points
```

Comment: Interesting. Just to absolutely confirm, the "self." part of self.points makes it so that the variable is the same throughout the class, sort of like how a variable within a function only works in that function unless you make it global?

Comment: "self" is just a variable that contains the instance. Writing score.print_points() is actually identical to writing Score.print_points(score). You are calling the print_point method in score, with the first argument (which is called self only by convention, it could technically be anything) passed being the instance